# How long is the Nijni-Novgorod trade fair?

Tags: french-language, historical-context, jules-verne, michel-strogoff

In Jules Verne, [*Michel Strogoff*, part 1 chapter 5](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Michel_Strogoff/Partie_1/Chapitre_5), when Michel arrives to Nijni-Novgorod, there's a huge trade fair going on in the city.  The text seems to give two contradictory numbers about how long the trade fair is.

> Nijni-Novgorod, qui en temps ordinaire ne compte que trente à trente-cinq mille habitants, en renfermait alors plus de trois cent mille, c’est-à-dire que sa population était décuplée. Cet accroissement était dû à la célèbre foire qui se tient dans ses murs pendant une période de **trois semaines**.
>
> [later]
>
> Tel était l’aspect de la plaine, tel il devait être pendant les **six semaines** que dure ordinairement la célèbre foire de Nijni-Novgorod.

Why do these two numbers differ?  What am I misreading?

(You can find [the text of the novel online on Wikisource](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Michel_Strogoff/Partie_1/Chapitre_5), and also [on Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/7442)).

I have originally noticed this contradiction in the Hungarian translation *Sztrogof Mihály*, Pesti Szalon Kvk. (1994), ISBN:963834024X, translated by *Supka Géza*, edited by *Gerencsér Zsuzsa*.  This translation doesn't always stick to the meaning of the original text, but in this case it does have both numbers.  I show the relevant quotes below.

> Nyizsnyij Novgorod, melynek lakossága általában nem több, mint harminc-harmincötezer lélek, ebben az időszakban több mint háromszázezret számlált, tehát megtöbbszöröződött.  Ennek az oka pedig a híres vásár volt, mely három hétig tartott a város falai között.
>
> […]
>
> Ősrégi szokás szerint még az is megesett ezen a hat hétig tartó Nyizsnyij Novgorod-i vásáron, hogy […]

[The English translation by Agnes Kinloch Kingston](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Michael_Strogoff/Chapter_V) [and the one found on Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1842/1842-h/1842-h.htm) does not mention a duration the second time in the text, so it does not have this contradiction.

Comment: Reading about the fair on [the Russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.9F.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81_.D1.8F.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.BA.D0.B8), maybe the duration changed over time: "In 1666 merchants came to the fair not only from all over Russia, but also from abroad, and it lasted 2 weeks." but then in the 19th century "The duration of the fair was more than a month: the flags were raised on July 15 and dropped on August 25."

Comment: @Randal'Thor The novel doesn't tell when exactly the story happened, but it's definitely after 1817 (chapter 5 says the fair was moved to Nijni-Novgorod), and probably significantly before 1876 (when the novel was published).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Almost all the dates are given only relative to the year: I believe Michel arrived to the fair on July 16 and left on the next day.

Comment: There's also a confusing passage in the (Google-translated) Wikipedia page: "The duration of the fair was more than a month: the flags were raised on July 15 and dropped on August 25. But this auction began in August and lasted until early September." So *something* lasted for ~6 weeks and something else laster for 2-3 weeks. We might need a Russian speaker to make sense of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, Jules Verne’s mistake.

[According to local historian](https://arzamas.academy/materials/2192) (Professor [Fedor Seleznev](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%B2,_%D0%A4%D1%91%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)'s lecture *История Нижегородской ярмарки* for [Arzamas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzamas_(website))) the trade fair lasted for just one day before *1641*, four weeks after that, and about six weeks from *1822*, when new place was chosen, and new facilities were built:

> Since then, the Nizhny Novgorod Fair has always opened on July 15, and
> ended on August 25 with the lowering of flags.

[Other sources](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/unknownhistory1917/nijegorodskaia-iarmarka-ekspocentr-xix-veka-5ebbc16c32c6750fba840360) (anonymous Yandex Zen web channel *неизвестная история*) specify that

> officially, the fair was held from July 15 to August 25, but in fact
> the trade continued until the beginning of September